# pandas use resample.sum I need to convert the result to the format I want?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

data

```
 [{"content": "11", "title": "刘德华", "info": "2020-01-13", "time": 1578877014},
                  {"content": "22", "title": "刘德", "info": "2020-01-24", "time": 1579877014},
                  {"content": "33", "title": "apple", "info": "2020-02-28", "time": 1582877014},
                  {"content": "55", "title": "app", "info": "2020-02-17", "time": 1581877014},
                  {"content": "22", "title": "appstore", "info": "2019-06-30", "time": 1561877014},
                  {"content": "44", "title": "banana", "info": "2020-02-28", "time": 1582876014},
                  {"content": "33", "title": "banana", "info": "2020-03-12", "time": 1584000882},
                  {"content": "44", "title": "banana", "info": "2018-03-12", "time": 1520842482},
                  {"content": "55", "title": "banana", "info": "2020-03-14", "time": 1584154305},
                  {"content": "66", "title": "banana", "info": "2019-03-14", "time": 1552531905},
                  {"content": "77", "title": "banana", "info": "2020-03-19", "time": 1584586305},
                  {"content": "88", "title": "banana", "info": "2019-11-07", "time": 1573095105},

                  ]
```

my code use reample.sum

```
s = pd.Series(data)
s.index =pd.to_datetime([i['time'] for i in self.dt], utc=True, unit='s').tz_convert('Asia/Shanghai')
cdata = pd.to_numeric(self.s.str.get(field), errors='coerce').resample('1y').sum()
```

i want to data:

```
[
{"content": "44", "title": "", "info": "", "time": 1546185600},
{"content": "176", "title": "", "info": "", "time": 1577721600},
{"content": "330", "title": "", "info": "", "time": 1609344000},]
```

but i print data

```
2018-12-31 00:00:00+08:00     44
2019-12-31 00:00:00+08:00    176
2020-12-31 00:00:00+08:00    330
```

How should I convert the data
i need to convert the result to the format I want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
cdata = pd.to_numeric(self.s.str.get(field), errors='coerce').resample('1y').sum()
cdata = cdata.to_json(orient records)
```

maybe.. i guess

or maybe

```
 cdata.to_dict(orient="rows")
```

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't turn `s` into series, but rather a dataframe:

```
# not series, but dataframe
s = pd.DataFrame(data)

# convert time index
s.index = pd.to_datetime(s['time'], unit='s', utc=True).dt.tz_convert('Asia/Shanghai')

# convert content to numeric
s['content'] = pd.to_numeric(s['content'], error='coerce')

# output
(s.resample('1Y').agg({'content':'sum'})
  .reindex(s.columns, axis=1, fill_value="")
  .assign(time=lambda x: x.index.astype('int64')//int(1e9))
  .to_dict('records')
)
```

Output:

```
[{'content': 44, 'title': '', 'info': '', 'time': 1546185600},
 {'content': 176, 'title': '', 'info': '', 'time': 1577721600},
 {'content': 330, 'title': '', 'info': '', 'time': 1609344000}]
```